# Источник сюжетов крыловских басен

Tags: литература

Здравствуйте!
Почитала интереснейшие ответы по поводу связи слова "проворонить" с басней Крылова и не только. И стало мне интересно: а Крылов хоть какие-то сюжеты для басен сам придумал или все брал от более старых авторов - от Эзопа и Федра до Лафантена?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 4):

За 30 лет им написано 204 басни, из них 67 — переводные или заимствованные, в основном из Эзопа и Лафонтена; в большинстве же произведений разрабатывались оригинальные сюжеты, их источник - русская жизнь.

Среди них выделяются социально-политические басни (и особо — басни о событиях 1812 г.), нравственно-философские, нравоучительные.Наиболее остры прямо метившие в верховную власть басни «Рыбья пляска» и «Пестрые овцы», в которой решение Льва истребить пестрых овец «законным» путем, принятое по совету Лисы: «...прикажи овец волкам пасти. // Не знаю, как-то мне сдается, // Что род их сам переведется» — напоминало современникам Крылова о разгроме профессуры Петербургского университета в 1822 г., осуществленном Министерством просвещения и Комитетом министров по желанию Александра I.

Несовершенство судебной системы и в целом государственного управления - в баснях «Лисица и Сурок», «Крестьяне и Река», «Волк и Мышонок», «Щука», «Крестьянин и Лисица», «Крестьянин и Овца».

Причиной общественных бед, по Крылову, может оказаться неумение правителей прямо взглянуть на нужды народа: в басне «Воспитание Льва» (1811).

Многие басни Крылова рисуют нравственное несовершенство стоящих у власти вельмож: «Оракул», «Осел», «Гуси», «Две собаки», «Сокол и Червяк», «Вельможа» и др. Мотив этот также перекликается с традициями жанра сатиры XVIII в. — и крыловский Осел, который по воле Зевеса стал ... скотиной превеликой.

Басни о войне 1812 года:

«Ворона и Курица» (1812) посвящена событиям сентября 1812 г. и может прочитываться и как сатира на Наполеона — обманувшийся французский император «попался, как ворона в суп», и как выпад против части дворянства, ослепленной галломанией и потому не осознавшей вовремя масштабов опасности. Стремление бездумно перенимать чужое ведет не просто к утрате собственной ценности, национального достоинства («Червонец», «Бочка») — оно может стоить свободы и жизни.

Басня «Волк на псарне» (1812) отразила тяжелое положение французской армии и попытку Наполеона вступить в переговоры с Кутузовым. Мудрость действий Кутузова в сравнении с молодыми нетерпеливыми, а иногда и неспособными полководцами Крылов показал в баснях «Обоз», «Щука и Кот»; раздоры армейского начальства отразились в басне «Раздел». Откликом на вступление русских войск в Париж стала басня «Чиж и Еж» (1814); однако своеобразно подводила итог циклу написанная в том же году басня «Пожар и Алмаз».

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, Крылов иносказательно изобразил в своих баснях как современную ему жизнь, так и многие исторические события, связанные с судьбой России. Басен с заимствованными сюжетами у него около 30, а все остальные - исконно свои. Н-р, "Волк в овчарне" (связано с войной 1812 г.), "Квартет" (осмеяние Государственного совета, созданного в 1801 г.), "Лебедь, Рак да Щука" (та же тема), "Хозяин и мыши"  и др. Если интересна тема, можно многое узнать по этой ссылке: http://nsportal.ru/ap/literaturnoe-tvorchestvo/istoriya-rossii-v-basnyah-iakrylova

Answer (score 0):

Крылов не написал сам ни одной басни. Все что он делал, так это переводил с французского и с русского на русский. Басни в переводе Крылова очень тяжелые для восприятия и не имеют художественной ценности, так как всего лишь навсего бездарный перевод.

Comment: Хорошо, когда литературный вкус соответствует познаниям в литературе. Хотя познания ещё можно немного расширить (прочесть статью в Википедию о Крылове хотя бы).